# MySQL SET and ENUM types in CakePHP framework

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need to use SET and ENUM types in my CakePHP 1.3 project. I found some advices, but all them are too old (2004-2006) and full of crazy methods, like modifying cake's core files. Also, CakePHP developers said that SET and ENUM types are not supported.

*Example*:

I have

```
SET('alpha','beta')
```

field, and I need to use this data as checkboxes in add & edit actions.

Is there any way to add normal support (Form helpers etc.) of SET and ENUM fields?